Getting compile errors when viewing generated protobuf class
I am using the following dependency in my spring boot app:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.26.1</version>
</dependency>

And also have installed protoc via homebew. Running protoc --version returns libprotoc 26.1.
I have compiled my .proto file which contains a simple structure which comprises of a few strings, bools and an enum.
But when i view the file in intellij, i get a lot of errors such as; Ambiguous method call: both 'RequestDto.getDescriptor()' and 'RequestDto.getDescriptor()' match etc.
I am on using Java version 21 with the language level set to SDK default.
And as a result, i cannot perform mvn clean install on my spring boot app.
Any ideaS?
